# If I use the ftp.exe in the cmd line and do the APPEND command, but the file does not exist on the remote host, will the file be created?

Tags: ftp, dos

If I use the ftp.exe in the cmd line and do the APPEND command, but the file does not exist on the remote host, will the file be created?

Answer (score 0):

On my ftp server it returned an error that the file could not be located.